# Questions about ios14 widgets -- fetching dynamic data from container app

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios14

I am mainly just looking for clarification or resources. Let me explain my situation.

I have an app that internally relies on an always-up-to-date database of items. I'd like to show off items that were released close to today's date. I originally thought I'd just query my database and fetch the relevant items from there. So I began the long process of updating target values so the widget could see my classes, etc... But that was such a HEADACHE.

I thought surely there must be a more lightweight method the designers had in mind, so I then read about "app groups" and being able to pass information via saved settings/preferences. So basically when the app runs, you store some data as json and then you can fetch that information in your widget.

But then, to my knowledge, the data won't update unless the user runs the app again. I was hoping I could keep this widget up to date even if the user hasn't used the app in a long time.

What exactly is the process I should be using to achieve this? Are "app groups" basically the only way to do this? Will I just have to accept that I will often times have stale data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to get data from a server using a network request? Or are you trying to get data from CoreData/UserDefaults within your application? WidgetKit allows you to make a network request when requesting a Timeline of entries, so you don't necessarily have to go through App Groups, but if the data is on device, then App Groups seems the easiest solution.

Comment: Well I have an internal sqlite database (not managed through CoreData or anything), so I was hoping to query that information directly from the widget. It looks like that's a really complicated process though, if I could get it to work at all without major refactoring. I instead decided to just have this information ready on a server so the widget can query for it from the server instead of the app's DB.